# Jetty with a custom JUL logger

Tags: java, jetty, java.util.logging

I feel this should be easier, or I am missing something obvious.

I am trying to use our custom JUL logging library with Jetty.   No matter where I put the JAR file for the custom logger, it is not found.   I have tried the usual suspects; /lib/, /lib/ext/, /WEB-INF/lib/ and even manually added it to the classpath.

```
2011-06-29 15:27:34.518::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
Can't load log handler "net.aw20.logshot.client.LogShotHandler"
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.aw20.logshot.client.LogShotHandler
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.aw20.logshot.client.LogShotHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
```

I am starting up Jetty using "-jar start.jar" technique.  Searching around, I have spotted a couple of threads that talk about this problem, but with no resolution.  Or if there was, they didn't answer with their solution.

Can anyone help on this front?

Thanks

Comment: does it work if you extract the class files in your jar file and place them in the WEB-INF/classes folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you start a Java application with "-jar", the normal classpath-arguments are not used any more. What you can do instead is to list the .jar file in a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. I.e. I have the following in one of my jar-files:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 20.6-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Built-By: user1
Bundle-Vendor: myCompany
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.1
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0.1
Class-Path: commons.jar lib/hibernate3.jar
```

and this way the jars are available as part of the Classpath.